Uniqueness of the Degree of Faithful Irreducible Representations
Can a group have two faithful irreducible unitary representations with distinct degrees? For example, if you were to find a faithful irreducible unitary representation of a group $G$ of dimension $\aleph_0,$ could you immediately deduce that any other faithful irreducible unitary representation must also have this dimension?

Every nontrivial representation of a simple group is faithful, so you can look at e.g. the character table of $A_5$; it has faithful irreducible unitary representations of degrees $3, 4, 5$.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you! Can you think of any with infinite dimension? I would be shocked to find that there can be faithful irred. unitary rep's of different infinite cardinal dimensions.

That seems more plausible to me but I'm not very familiar with infinite-dimensional unitary representations.

This is a partial answer, as I don't know in general. Assume that the field $k$ is "small", i.e., $|k|\leq |G|$. If $V$ is a vector space of dimension greater than $|k|$ then $|V|=\dim(V)$. Also, $|V|$ is the same as the cardinality of linear transformations from $V$ to $V$, so if $G$ embeds in $End(V)$ then $|V|\geq |G|$. On the other hand, the $G$-orbit of a vector in $V$ has cardinality at most $|V|$, so any irreducible representation has cardinality at most $|G|$.

@DavidA.Craven: do you mean, in your last sentence, "the $G$-orbit of a vector in $V$ has cardinality at most $|G|$, so any irreducible representation has dimension (and hence cardinality) at most $|G|$"?

@krm2233 Yes, I skipped a step. It was only a comment, so I thought that bit was fine, since the same trick (which definitely requires $k$ to not be too big) was used earlier.

@DavidA.Craven It wasn't the skipped step I meant to draw attention to -- I agree with you that that should be fine to elide given the trick was already in play. I just meant to flag the stupid point that your original comment has a typo in that it says the G-orbit has cardinality at most $|V|$ rather than $|G|$.

@krm2233 Ah, right. Yes, you are correct, I didn't notice that, even after you mentioned it! Thanks.

Qiaochu already provided a counterexample for finite-dimensional cases in the comments. Here is an infinite-dimensional counterexample, constructed using $C^\ast$-algebra and von Neumann algebra machinery. There should be much more simpler constructions, but this is the only one I came up with.
Fix a separable II$_1$ factor $M$. Let $U(M)$ be its unitary group. Then its center is $U(1)$, the group of scalar operators. Let,
$$G = (U(M) \times U(M))/\{(z, z): z \in U(1)\}$$
Now, consider the following two representations of the group:

Let $H = L^2(M)$, the standard representation of $M$, which comes equipped with both left and right actions of $M$. Let $\pi: G \to U(H)$ be given by,

$$\pi([(g, h)])\xi = g\xi h^{-1}, \forall \xi \in H$$
Note that, for any $z \in U(1)$, $z\xi z^{-1} = \xi$, so this is indeed a well-defined homomorphism. Furthermore, we note that it is faithful. Indeed, if $g\xi h^{-1} = \xi$ for all $\xi \in H$, then in particular, $ghh^{-1} = h \Rightarrow g = h$. But then, when $g = h$, $g\xi g^{-1} = \xi$ for all $\xi \in H$ implies $g \in Z(M)$, so $g \in U(1)$, i.e., $(g, h) \in \{(z, z): z \in U(1)\}$.
We also note that it is irreducible. Indeed, $\pi([(g, 1)])$ gives all unitaries in the left action of $M$ while $\pi([(1, h)])$ gives all unitaries in the right action of $M$. The left and right actions together generate the entirety of $\mathbb{B}(L^2(M))$, so the representation is irreducible. Since $M$ is separable, $H = L^2(M)$ is a separable Hilbert space. Thus, $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation of dimension $\aleph_0$.

By Krein-Milman, $M$ has a pure state and thus an irreducible representation $\phi: M \to \mathbb{B}(H)$ for some Hilbert space $H$. It is known that, if $H$ is separable, then $\phi$ must be normal. (See Theorem V.5.1 in Takesaki’s Theory of Operator Algebras I.) But if $\phi$ is normal, then as $M$ is of type II$_1$, $\phi(M)$ and thus $\phi(M)’$ must be of type II. However, the representation is irreducible, so $\phi(M)’ = \mathbb{C}$, which is a contradiction, so $H$ must be non-separable. Note also that, as II$_1$ factors are simple as $C^\ast$-algebras, $\phi$ must be faithful.

Now, let $\pi: G \to U(H \otimes \overline{H})$ be defined by,
$$\pi([(g, h)]) = \phi(g) \otimes \overline{\phi(h)}$$
Since $z \otimes \overline{z} = 1$ for any scalar $z \in U(1)$, we again have $\pi$ is a well-defined homomorphism. $\pi$ is also faithful, as $\phi(g) \otimes \overline{\phi(h)} = 1$ implies both $\phi(g)$ and $\phi(h)$ are scalars, in which case it is easy to check that $\phi(g) \in U(1)$ and $\phi(h) = \phi(g)$. But $\phi$ is faithful, so,
$$(g, h) = (\phi(g), \phi(g)) \in \{(z, z): z \in U(1)\}$$
This verifies that $\pi$ is faithful. Finally, it is irreducible as $\pi([(g, 1)])$ generates $\phi(M) \otimes 1$ and thus generates $\mathbb{B}(H) \otimes 1$, as $\phi$ is irreducible. Similarly, $\pi([(1, h)])$ generates $1 \otimes \mathbb{B}(\overline{H})$, so $\pi(G)$ generates the entirety of $\mathbb{B}(H \otimes \overline{H})$, i.e., $\pi$ is irreducible. Hence, $G$ also has a faithful irreducible representation on a non-separable Hilbert space.

The reason I asked this question was because I was interested in the representations of $S_\mathbb{N}$ (the automorphisms of the set $\mathbb{N}$) with a particular topology. I suppose I got lucky since I was able to show that my conjecture held in this case, i.e. every faithful irreducible has degree $\aleph_0.$

@MilesGould You meant that all faithful irreducible representations of $S_\mathbb{N}$ continuous under your particular topology are of degree $\aleph_0$? I suppose that’s not that surprising. In general, if you have an uncountable group, it’s always a good idea to consider some topology on it. Even in the example in my answer, if you equip $G$ with the SOT topology and only consider strongly continuous representations, you also get the only faithful irreps have dimension $\aleph_0$. It’s only when topology is ignored that these bizarre counterexamples begin to show up.
